# How to check value of a given JVM flag?

Tags: java, jvm

I have setup in my dockerfile:

```
ENTRYPOINT [ "java", "-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true", "-jar","/xxx/xxx.jar" ]
```

but now when I list all the flags that are on:

```
RUN java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal
RUN echo $?
```

I can't see `preferIPv4Stack` anywhere. How to I make sure that `preferIPv4Stack` is set?

Comment: `java.net.preferIPv4Stack` is system property, not a JVM flag.

Comment: @rkosegi Am I setting it properly and just verifying it badly, or I've done both things wrong?

Comment: btw to use `PrintFlagsFinal` you should also pass `-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions` IIRC

Comment: @rkosegi It worked both with and without it, but then how should I print Java system properites, as this is the issue then.

Comment: I don't think there is JVM CLI option to dump system properties, but you should be able to obtain it via JMX

Comment: @rkosegi So last question then. Do I set the property correctly, because this is what I am trying to verify.

Comment: yes, system property is passed correctly

Answer (score 0):

You can use JVM tool to check the java process these parameters,

> jcmd pid VM.flags
>
> jinfo -flags pid
> jmap -heap pid

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have these tools avaialble in my docker image, do I set this property correctly via `ENTRYPOINT`?

Answer (score 0):

As @rkosegi pointed out `java.net.preferIPv4Stack` is a system property.
If `jcmd` is available you can list all system properties via `jcmd <PID> VM.system_properties`.